# skrollr.js relative mode activating right after load

Tags: javascript, skrollr

Let's say that I have an element which is 1000px from the top of the page, if I would gave him this attribute `data-300-top="background: brown;"` I would have thought it would get a brown background when I scroll roughly 700px(so it's 300px from the top of the viewport). But for some reason it gets brown right away.

Strangely enough, when I put second attribute there, something like this for example

```
data-100-top="background: green;" 
data-200-top="background: brown;"
```

it gets brown right away, but becomes green when I scroll so the element is 100px from the top of the viewport.

I don't understand it at all. Isn't it a bit inconsistent? And if this is the expected behaviour, how do I make it so it only triggers when it meets the conditions?

here's the example with bg being set right away 
http://jsbin.com/neqolu/1/edit?html,output

and here with the second attr working properly 
http://jsbin.com/kalora/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed expected behaviour.

See https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/660